# UIAccessibility Tableview Scrolling Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have implemented Accessibility for a custom table view.
Where I enabled the accessibility for all the subview of table cell like imageview,label,button,textfields.

I am facing 2 issues after implementing accessibility.

1. Because of the the accessibility frame focus the tableviewcell frame is acting so weird. It goes either left or right on voiceover swipe event.Focus making the view frame to align based on the selection.
2. If the number of cells are more then scrolling is not working. Till the cells are visible accessibility is working fine. Once the focus goes to invisible cells some time the tableview is scrolling according to the voiceover selections but not as expected.

I have implemented these following methods.

```
-(BOOL)isAccessibilityElement
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
{
    return self.subviews.count;
}

-(id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.subviews objectAtIndex:index];
}

-(NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element
{
    return [self.subviews indexOfObject:element];
}

-(BOOL)shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren
{
    return YES;
}
```

I read that these methods will not work in viewcontroller. so I am implementing these in cell class.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this accessibility Issues? Please help with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean with a custom table view? Not a UITableView?

Comment: Yes, it is uitableview but cells are customized.

Comment: So the container methods that you listen in your question is implemented in the cell class?

Comment: Yes David. I implemented those in cell class.

Comment: And the subviews are the labels and such that you are expecting and not things like the backgroundView and the containerView?

Comment: accessibility is focusing on the subviews like label or button. But the entire contentView of cell is shifting either right or left according to the selection.

Comment: I solved this issue by removing all the above methods. Enabled the accessibility for cell contentview. Now it is working fine, but voiceover will not read in correct order. I feel that for Accessibility user reading order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1 can occur if your subviews (labels, buttons, as you mention) have frames that extend to larger than the size of the screen.

One visual way to verify if this is the case is to change the color of the subview: you will notice on the accessibility focus shift if a particular subview extends further than your other views.

Decrease the size of your subview frames to resolve.